# attempting to upload Julia package "registry dirty" attempting to add xvfb

Tags: package, julia

I'm trying to upload a Julia package and it keept giving me this error:

```
┌ Info: xvfb: 
└   xvfb = "/usr/bin/xvfb-run"
[ Info: Attempting to `Pkg.add` the package
     Copying registry from `~/work/General/General`
      Copied registry `General` to `/tmp/jl_BJLRTv/registries/General`
[ Info: Attempting to `Pkg.add` package...
    Updating registry at `/tmp/jl_BJLRTv/registries/General`
┌ Error: Some registries failed to update:
│     — `/tmp/jl_BJLRTv/registries/General` — registry dirty
```

I've removed all the dependencies and still get it. I found out that:

> Xvfb or X virtual framebuffer is a display server implementing the X11 display server protocol.

[Wikpedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)

Is there any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show what command you're running/what your workflow is to publish the package to the registry?

Comment: @SundarR this is the workflow file: https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General/actions/runs/7051705114/workflow?pr=96260